# "before each" hook error while run truffle test command

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, test

I ran `truffle test` command on my project for testing but I got an error like this:

1. "before each" hook for "1- should be return true Pauser Role for account[0]"

why I'm getting this error?

My test scripts are below:

```
const Loyalty = artifacts.require("Loyalty.sol");
const AdminUpgradeability = artifacts.require("AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol");
//const assertLib = require("truffle-assertions");

let LoyaltyContractObj;

contract ("Test for Pausable and PauserRole Contracts", (accounts) =>{

    beforeEach(async() =>{
        LoyaltyContractObj= await Loyalty.at(AdminUpgradeability.address);
        console.log(accounts[1])

    });
    
    // PAUSER ROLE

    it("1- should be return true Pauser Role for account[0]", async()=>{
        const res= await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[0]);
        assert.isTrue(res, "the account is not Pauser. Please check the contract!!");
    });

    it("2- should be return False Pauser Role for account[1]", async()=>{
        const res= await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[1]);
        assert.isFalse(res, "the account is Pauser. Please check the contract!!");
    });

    it("3-should be return true Pauser Role for account[1]", async()=>{
       await LoyaltyContractObj.addPauser(accounts[1]);
       const res= await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[0]);

       assert.isTrue(res, "The account[1] is not pauser. Please check the contract code! ");
    });

    it("4- should be return False for same address is already Pauser", async()=> {
        try{await LoyaltyContractObj.addPauser(accounts[1]);
        throw null;
        }
        catch(e){
        assert.isFalse(false);}
    });

    it("5- should be return False, Pauser role for accounts[1].", async()=> {
        await LoyaltyContractObj.removePauser(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0]});
        const res = await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[1]);

        assert.isFalse(res, "the account[1] is pauser. Please Check it!");
    });


    // PAUSABLE

    it("6- should be return False for is Paused the contract.", async()=> {
        const res = await LoyaltyContractObj.paused();
        assert.isFalse(res, "Contract is Paused. Check it!");
        });
      
    it("7- should be return True for is Paused the contract.", async()=> {
        await LoyaltyContractObj.pause();
        const res = await LoyaltyContractObj.paused();
        assert.isTrue(res, "Contract is not Paused. That is a problem! :( Check it!");
    });

    it("8- should be return True, Pauser role for accounts[0].", async()=> {
        await LoyaltyContractObj.addPauser(accounts[1],{from: accounts[0]});
        const res = await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[1]);

        assert.isTrue(res, "the account[1] is not pauser. Please Check it!");
    });

    // it("9- should be return False, Pauser role for accounts[0].", async()=> {
    //     await LoyaltyContractObj.renouncePauser({from: accounts[0]});
    //     const res = await LoyaltyContractObj.isPauser(accounts[0]);

    //     assert.isFalse(res, "the account[0] is pauser. Please Check it!");
    // });
});
```

Error snippets:

```
  Contract: Test for Pausable and PauserRole Contracts
    1) "before each" hook for "1- should be return true Pauser Role for account[0]"

  Contract: Test for Ownable contract
    2) 1- should be equal accounts[0] to owner address
    > No events were emitted
    3) 2- should be not equal accounts[2] to owner address
    > No events were emitted
    4) 3- should be new owner account[2]
    > No events were emitted
    5) 4- should be not equal accounts[0] to owner address
    > No events were emitted
    6) 5- should be new owner account[0]
    > No events were emitted
    7) 6- should be not equal accounts[2] the owner address
    > No events were emitted
```

Also my truffle version is:

```
Truffle v5.1.14-nodeLTS.0 (core: 5.1.13)
Solidity - 0.5.1 (solc-js)
Node v12.19.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

what would I do?

thank you,

Comment: You're not seriously expecting to get an answer here without showing your code, are you?????

Comment: sorry you're right I'm editing properly :)

Comment: You should `console.log(AdminUpgradeability.address)` in order to realize that it is `undefined`.

Comment: I have successfully used this many times before. So how can I test proxy contracts? I could not understand why it is like this @goodvibration